# Can inner functions always be safely defined outside of the function?

Tags: python

For example:

```
def increment(number):
...     def inner_increment():
...         return number + 1
...     return inner_increment()
```

The `inner_increment()` can be taken out and defined in the same scope as `increment()`. Is that true?

EDIT:

```
def increment(number):
   return inner_increment(number)

def inner_increment(number):
   return number+1
```

Comment: If you try moving that function out you'll see that definitely isn't true. If it's not defined inside increment, it's not closed over number.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why do you think they are different when I move them out?

Comment: In that case you've also changed how, not just where, the function is defined.

Comment: They are different because you've made them different. Specifically, what @jonrsharpe is saying is that the function prototypes/definitions of `inner_increment` are not the same across your two snippets. The first version takes no parameters, while the second version takes one. By changing the definition of the function, you've made it "safe", but, to be precise, simply moving it outside of `increment` with no other changes  would not be "safe".

Comment: So I can always avoid using nested functions in Python if I desire. Right?

Answer (score 0):

"Always" and "safely" are very sweeping words, involving a variety of assumptions and perhaps a value judgement or two.

As you have done, yes, it's possible to extract a nested function -- provided that you move all of its required outer scope collateral into the parameter list.  Anything that `inner` assumed from the outer scope, now must be passed as an argument.

You also need to ensure that you don't collide with any other `inner_increment` symbol in the outer scope.